# Ayuda con esta consulta

Tags: c#, mysql

Estoy trayendo información de **varias tablas** para un reporte general de información *en base a la fecha* pero el problema es que me duplica información

```
    SELECT insumos.fecha,insumos.producto,insumos.cantidad,
 mano_obra.nombre,mano_obra.pago,mano_obra.fecha,
 mantenimiento.descripcion,mantenimiento.gasto,mantenimiento.fecha,
 combustible.vehiculo,combustible.gasolina,combustible.fecha FROM
 insumos,mano_obra,mantenimiento,combustible WHERE insumos.fecha 
between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-01' and mano_obra.fecha 
between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-01' and mantenimiento.fecha 
between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-01' and combustible.fecha 
between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
```

resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de como debería ser:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que pueda ayudarme en esto, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Has intentado hacer un DISTINCT al momento de la consulta. El DISTINCT se utiliza para que la consulta no traiga valores duplicados. Acá hay un ejemplo. [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: No va a funcionar los registros no son iguales

Comment: Raul el DISTINCT manda la misma información

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta la forma en que estas agrupando las tablas.

... FROM tableA, tableB ...

lo que esta pasando es SQL realiza una combinación, entonces por cada registro de la tablaB relaciona todos los registros de la tablaA. Es por esto que se te duplican.

Si las tablas tienes la mista estructura (que no creo), podrías usar la clausula UNION, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONAS (
  ID VARHCAR(10),
  NAME VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE VEHICULOS(
 ID VARCHAR(10),
 NAME VARHCAR(50)
);
```

Con la estructura de las dos tablas anteriores podrías hacer los siguiente:

```
 SELECT * FROM PERSONAS 
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM VEHICULOS;
```

La otra solución es si tus tablas tienen relación, si la tienen puedes unas INNER JOIN.

Comment: como puedes ver es diferente estructura, utilizar _union_ no me funciona